# Not able to download a file from OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

According to Microsoft Graph's documentation, the API to download file contents of a file in my OneDrive is:

```
/beta/me/drive/items/01UG2T5D6KU5GACQUPCFE3AMTN47BTTSA6/content
```

however it is returning

```
Failure - Status Code 0,    
{
    "isTrusted": true
}
```

If I just do

```
/beta/me/drive/items/01UG2T5D6KU5GACQUPCFE3AMTN47BTTSA6
```

it returns the correct file metadata - so this means the file exists so any clues why Graph cannot fetch the content

Comment: Could you please include the code you're using to call the API?

Comment: I believe this Graph Explorer returns this error - it doesn't really support downloading content. An application that makes the same call should be fine.

Comment: @john are you able to resolve this issue? I am having a same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content`

Ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content

If you're using Dotnet SDK for Graph, you could use

```
graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(itemPath).Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still getting same error. Note: I'm trying from _Graph Explorer_