# Not able to convert .docx file to pdf using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

For my project need, I need to convert MS format documents in to pdf. I started exploring microsoft graph API. For easiness I started with graph explorer(using my corporate and personal login) on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer.

I have added sample document in drive and using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children`, I got *itemId* of my file.

Now, I am trying to convert it into pdf using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{itemId}/content?format=pdf`. But I am always getting response as **Failure - Status Code 0**

Anyone has an idea how to fix this issue?

Here is an attached screen shot of microsoft graph explorer

[image]

**Note**: I found similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137121/not-able-to-download-a-file-from-onedrive/51945888#comment91392225_51945888) but it is not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I assume you want to convert .docx file to pdf using Microsoft graph API.

Based on my test, we can use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{itemId}/content?format=pdf`.

It will return a failure response when run it in graph explore. However, when we use the develop control panel, we can get this request and response.

Location properties are in the response headers. It is the address of the converted file.

We can use this URI to review or download the document that converted.

The request URL:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{itemId}/content?format=pdf`

The response may like this:

[image]

Comment: >when we use the develop control panel, we can get this request and response.                          

I did not get "develop control panel". Can you please give me more detail about? Note: I am looking this solution for _Java_ base application.

Comment: When we use the Graph Explore, we can press F12. If you use the program, you can debug this application.